# Continuity with $\epsilon$, $\delta$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity

My question is the following:

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function:
\begin{equation} f(x)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  {x^2}  & \mbox{if }  {x \text{ is rational}} \\
  {x+2} & \mbox{if } {x \text{ is not rational}}
 \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
Find all points, if any, where $f$ is continuous.

I’m using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition stated as follows:

“Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $p$ be a limit point of $E$. Suppose $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is continuous at $p$ if for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for $x\in E$, if $|x-p|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(p)| < \epsilon$."

I’ve attempted a solution with split cases for $p$ rational and $p$ not rational, and have been working with arbitrary $\epsilon$ and attempting to construct $\delta$ for each of the above cases to see under what constraints $p$ might be a continuous point of the function. I’m working on it but it’s becoming quickly tedious and I think I’m going about it the wrong way - any chance of some help?

Comment: Have you seen the result that the indicator function of the rationals is nowhere continuous? Based on that, at which points would you expect your function to be continuous and where is it definitely discontinuous?

Comment: The intuition for this is as follows. Look at $g(x) = x^2$ and $h(x) = x + 2$. The $x$'s for which $g(x) = h(x)$ have a chance of being a point where $f$ is continuous, because near there, the value of $f(x)$ for rational $x$ and irrational $x$ are close together.

Comment: Look for the roots of the equation $x^2 = x +2$. If exists a solution, try continuity there.

Comment: @Johanna, I haven’t seen such a result - or perhaps I simply haven’t heard the phrase “indicator function”.

Comment: @Magdiragdag - that’s a bit helpful. I’ll think about that a bit!

Comment: @user192271 The indicator function takes the value $1$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $0$ otherwise - it indicates if the value is in the given set. Proving that that one is discontinuous everywhere might help here (I assume you know that the rationals are dense in the reals).

Comment: Are you bounded to use the epsilon-delta method here? There is also the fact that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$ for each sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x$.

Comment: @Johanna I have seen that result - and I do know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. I simply hadn’t heard of that as a reference to that particular function. I shall think on your comment for a while.